LOAD spatial query is not working in DuckDb-swift for iOS app
I have added the duckdb-swift package into my iOS project and i am trying to load the GPKG file using ST_Read spatial function.
following is my code
// Get the document directory path for the persistent database file
       let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
       let dbURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("gpkg_test.duckdb")
       
       // Initialize DuckDB with persistent storage
       let db = try DuckDB.Database(store: .file(at: dbURL))
       let connection = try db.connect()
       do {
           let res = try? connection.query("INSTALL spatial;")
           print(res)
           print("Spatial extension installation attempted.")
       }catch let error as DuckDB.DatabaseError {
           print("Database error during spatial extension installation: \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
       } catch {
           print("General error during spatial extension installation: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       }
       do {
           let res = try? connection.query("LOAD spatial;")
           print(res)
           print("Spatial extension loading attempted.")
       }catch let error as DuckDB.DatabaseError {
           print("Database error during spatial extension installation: \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
       } catch {
           print("General error during spatial extension installation: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       }
       
       if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: gpkgFilePath) {
           print("GeoPackage file found at path: \(gpkgFilePath)")
           
       } else {
           print("GeoPackage file not found at path: \(gpkgFilePath)")
           result(FlutterError(code: "FILE_NOT_FOUND", message: "GeoPackage file not found", details: nil))
           return
       }
       
     
   
       // Ensure the path is properly sanitized
        let sanitizedPath = gpkgFilePath.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
       
       // Attempt to create a table by reading data from the GeoPackage file
       do {
           var res = try connection.query("CREATE TABLE federal_lands AS SELECT * FROM ST_Read('\(sanitizedPath)');")
           print("Table 'federal_lands' created successfully.\(res)")
       } catch {
           print("Error creating table: \(error)")
           result(FlutterError(code: "QUERY_ERROR", message: "Failed to create table: \(error.localizedDescription)", details: nil))
       }
       

I am getting response on Install but on let res = try? connection.query("LOAD spatial;") i am getting nil, Therefore i am unable to execute the ST_Read query. How can i do that?
if I tried to run the query i got following exception
Error creating table: connectionQueryError(reason: Optional("Catalog Error: Table Function with name \"st_read\" is not in the catalog, but it exists in the spatial extension.\n\nPlease try installing and loading the spatial extension:\nINSTALL spatial;\nLOAD spatial;\n\n"))

Error querying table: connectionQueryError(reason: Optional("Catalog Error: Table with name federal_lands does not exist!\nDid you mean "pg_depend"?"))
Please help if you can, thanks in advance.
